# traverse through the table and update columns with Null values

Tags: mysql

Iam working on MYSQL and need a stored procedure that will traverse through table A which has 100 columns and 50,000+ rows and for all Null values found in the table the SP will update it with blank values.

eg
UPDATE table A SET column1=' ' where column1 IS NULL;
column1 is mixture of null and filled and blank rows,but i want to update only null rows.

I do not want to hardcode the column names..want to fetch the columns one by one in the stored procedure itself.is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically fetch the column names from your tables.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
```

And combine this using inner queries.

Comment: some of my columns have datatype as int...can such columns be made blank where there is null

Answer (score 0):

Use the mysql ifnull function.You will need the below for all hundred columns. This can be used on string/char as well as integer fields.

```
update table 
set 
field1=ifnull(field1, " "),
field2=ifnull(field2, " "),
field3=ifnull(field3, 0),
field4=ifnull(field4, "")....
```

If you don't want to hardcode the column names, you can build the above query as per the other answer:

```
 SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
```

For each of the above rows, build a concatenated update statement.

```
DEClARE usercursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';

declare updatesql varchar(3000);

set updatesql = "update TABLE set ";

OPEN usercursor
get_users:LOOP
FETCH usercursor into v_username;

set updatesql = concat(v_username,"=ifnull(",updatesql)
set updatesql = concat(v_username,",' '),",updatesql)

END LOOP get_users
```